# Using the THREE.js CSS2DRenderer to position HTML elements from the top left

Tags: javascript, three.js

The CSS2DRenderer allows me to place an HTML element in a scene based on a 3D position, which can in turn correspond to some object placed in the 3D scene. For example, I can do:

```js
const mesh; // <some other mesh in the scene>

const el = document.createElement('div')
el.innerHTML = 'hello world'
const objectCSS = new CSS2DObject(el)
objectCSS.position.set(0, 0, 0)

mesh.add(objectCSS)
```

This will place the `hello world` div directly centered on the mesh, e.g.

```
_________________
|               |
|  hello world  |
|_______________|
```

How could I change the coordinates of the `hello world` div so that it is placed with respect to the top left of the div, instead of with respect to the center of the div? e.g.

```
 _________________
|               |
|       hello world  
|_______________|
```

EDIT: Note that the goal is not to just offset the text. I want to change the alignment. So for example, if I was just trying to offset, more text would look like like this:

```
_________________
|               |
|  hello world blah blah blah
|_______________|
```

wheres changing the alignment would look like this

```
_________________
|               |
|       hello world blah blah blah
|_______________|
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up being able to do this by utilizing a few nested div containers. My final code ended up looking something like this:

```js
const mesh; // <some other mesh in the scene>

// Create the relevant html elements.
const el = document.createElement('div')
const container = document.createElement('div');
const inner = document.createElmeent('div');

// Add styling.
container.style.display = 'flex'
container.style.flexDirection = 'column'
container.style.width = 'fit-content'  // needed to 'reset' the width calculations

// Set the text.
inner.innerHTML = 'HELLO WORLD'

// Set the rest of the THREE object.
const objectCSS = new CSS2DObject(el)
objectCSS.position.set(0, 0, 0)
objectCSS.element.style.overflow = 'visible'
objectCSS.element.style.width = '1px'  // I dont know if this is strictly needed
objectCSS.element.style.height = '1px'

mesh.add(objectCSS)
```

Comment: and what happened to container and inner?

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same problem. Lines 131 or 135 in the [CSS2DRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js)  the the transform to `translate(-50%,-50%)` to center the html element around the given position. Probably the best fix would be to have some sort of control over this when creating the `CSS2DObject`, maybe passing an optional argument argument? It might be worth making a PR?

Comment: I just realised that although you can set the transform to translate(50%) on the CSS2Object, you could set it to a child element ( the same as the suggested answer by theahura) and that would provide the answer that you are looking for..

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this same problem and discovered that the CSS2DObject has a `center` property.

Doing:

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.textContent = `Some text in the div`;

element.className = 'OPTIONAL_CSS_CLASSES_HERE';

element.style.left = '50px'; // positioning works

const objectCSS = new CSS2DObject(element);
objectCSS.center.x = 0;
objectCSS.center.y = 0;
```

did exactly what I wanted, which is aligning the top left of the div to the screen location of the 3D point.

This example is also offset 50px using the `element.style.left` attribute. You don't need this if you just want the box top left aligned, it's just for demonstration purposes.

Edit:
Also, setting:

```
objectCSS.center.x = 1;
objectCSS.center.y = 1;
```

Will align your div to the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a position on `objectCSS`, it will apply as an offset from the mesh.

Try: `objectCSS.position.set(10, 0, 0)`

See this example for more details: https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label

Specifically on this line: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/css2d_label.html#L132

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't accomplish what I'm looking for. I agree this will provide an offset, but the actual div is still centered. As evidence, if I make the inner text of the div longer, the div will stretch to the right and to the left, instead of just continuing out to the right

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just adding a container between the css2dObject parent and the content, like this:

```html
<div class="css2dObject">
    <div class="container" style="transform: translate(50%, 50%)"><!-- here -->
        <div class="content">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This container simply cancels the `translate(-50%,-50%)` set by the css2drenderer on the css2dObject. But I agree with @Jonathan Davidson, there should be a cleaner approach, maybe I'll make a PR when I have time.